# Three cryptic clues from 7 Directory magazine

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

Rainwear wrapped around heartless lothario (6)
ANSWER: Golash

It's not drunk at the Officer's Mess - the public can't buy either (7,4)
ANSWER: Private Sale

Improve at noon? (5)
ANSWER: Amend

I understand the definition but I don't fully understand the wordplay.

Please explain?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling (take our [tour])! Could you add to your question where you found these clues? Thanks!

Comment: Also, these are three entirely separate questions, and will lead to three entirely separate answers; they'd be better off individually

Comment: Hello, I found the clues in the 7 Directory (small local magazine delivered around Brighton and Hove). Some were in the November issue and some were in the October issue. I will remember to write them as individual questions in the future, but for now, as I have put them all in one post, if somebody could answer them in the one post that would be lovely. 

Comment: GOLASH doesn't appear in the dictionary, is the proper answer GALOSH?  In the same clue, is "wrapped" correct?  I would expect to see "wound".

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the first one. GALOSH means rainwear, and heartless lothario could be LO (lothario without the middle letters). But that would require "wrapped" to mean GASH which I don't think it does.

The second one is PRIVATES' ALE (something not drunk at the Officer's Mess) = PRIVATE SALE (something the public can't buy).

The third one could be AMEND (improve) = A.M. END (the end of the morning = at noon).

Comment: I expect that "wrapped" should be "wound"

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally misspelt the first answer, it should be GALOSH. That's the answer I got, but I couldn't figure out the "wrapped around" part either. I didn't know if the setter had missed out a word, but as you say, it could be that "wrapped" was actually meant to be "wound" and the setter has just made a mistake. That would definitely make sense. I'll try and find out.

Comment: The second clue, I wasn't sure what "it's not drunk" was referring to, because I can see the word "ate" inside private, so I wondered if it was getting at something that is eaten rather than drunk. I saw "privates' ale" in the answer but that confused me because ale is a drink that IS drunk....which is not what the clue says. I also wasn't sure whether "mess" was referring to an anagram of something.

Comment: @Dee a Private is not an officer and would therefore not be allowed in the Officer's Mess, so the Private's Ale would not be consumed there.  ("Mess" is short for "Mess Hall", which is the military term for their dining area.)